# Passing multiple states in react context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have a context that should pass down in the tree multiple states.
Which is the correct approach to set Provider's value?

1. Creating an object in place doesn't work since it is re-built at every re-render, causing the child to re-render as well also if the actual content of the context didn't change (because a new object is created, with a different memory address, causing the child to think the object changed).

How should I pass the context?

```
//Example:
interface Context {
 state1: number,
 state2: number,
}

const MyContext = React.createContext<Context|null>(null)

const MyFC: React.FC = (props)=>{
 const [state1,setState1] = useState<number>(0) //To pass down
 const [state2,setState2] = useState<number>(0) //To pass down
 const [state3,setState3] = useState<number>(0) //Not to pass down

 return(
   <MyContext.Provider value={????}>
      {/* components */}
   <MyContext>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options to pass down complex states in a context are multiple.

**Option 1: Split contexts that don't change together**

If elements composing a context are not tightly related consider **splitting the context into different contexts**. In this way you can pass single states without having to handle the problem of "unifying" states.

**Option 2: use useReducer to combine related states**

> When using useState hook is advised to create a separate state for
> each element since, unlike the state in class components, updating
> single elements of a state can lead to unnecessary complexity.

Use state is the most common tool to save state in functional components.

However, when more complex states (and state management) are needed, **useReducer** can be used to wrap up states in a single object. Then you can pass reducer's state as value for the context

```
function reducer(state,action) {
 switch(action.type){
   //Cases:
   //.... (works like redux reducer)
   default:
     return state
 }
}

const MyContext = React.createContext<Context|null>(null)

const MyFC: React.FC = (props)=>{
 const [compressedState,dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,{state1:0,state2:0})
 const [state3,setState3] = useState<number>(0) //Not to pass down

 return(
   <MyContext.Provider value={compressedState}>
       {/* components */}
   <MyContext>
 )
}
```

**Option 3: useMemo**

When neither of the previous options are feasible, useMemo is the way to go.
Simply combine all the elements that needs to be passed to create a value that updates only when at least one of the dependencies changes.

```
const MyContext = React.createContext<Context|null>(null)

const MyFC: React.FC = (props)=>{
 const [state1,setState1] = useState<number>(0) //To pass down
 const [state2,setState2] = useState<number>(0) //To pass down
 const [state3,setState3] = useState<number>(0) //Not to pass down

 const contextValue= useMemo(()=>{
   return{
    state1: state1,
    state2: state2
   }
 },[state1,state2]);

 return(
   <MyContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
       {/* components */}
   <MyContext>
 )
}
```

**Final note on useMemo**
Use memo becomes useful also when we need to pass both elements of useState (state and set state) or useReducer (state and dispatch).

In context, we should always **avoid** to put inside the `value` prop an inline object. As said at the beginning of the post, this object is re-created at every render (new memory address) causing the hooks checking to it to re-render (since the observed memory value changed) as well down in the widget tree.

Use memo can become handful in this scenario since it allows to avoid passing an inline object:

```
//Example for useReducer. Works also with useState.

const contextValue = useMemo(() => {
  return { state, dispatch };
}, [state, dispatch]);
```

Sources:

- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156
- https://hswolff.com/blog/how-to-usecontext-with-usereducer/

Comment: I still don't understand why useMemo is needed. Under what situation does it cause waste?

Comment: @NamLêQuý the useEffect hook does not a shallow comparison of the fields of an object but, to verify if an object is changed, it just looks at its address in memory. At every render, if not memorized, the object is re-created despite its field didn't change. This implies that the new object will be stored at a new memory address. Now, to the useEffect hook, this will seem as if the object changed, and it will execute again, causing a new render. In this scenario, you easily end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: I have another question. In `option 3: useMemo`, how can I pass `setState` to use in the child component?

Comment: If you have to pass only setState you can avoid using the useMemo hook and pass it directly to the provider (and then use a useContext hook in the child to retrieve it). However if you need to pass both you can memorize the do const `contextValue = useMemo(() => { return { state, setState }; }, [state, state]);` and then pass ContextValue to the provider. Then in the children you can either use decomposition `{ state, setState } = useContext(...)` or retrieve the context value and do `contextValue.setState(..)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a keyed array to value :

```
value={{'state1':[state1,setstate1],'state2':[state2,setstate2]}}
```

And then you can retrieve each data :

```
const context = React.useContext(MyContext);
const [state1,setstate1] = context['state1'];
const [state2,setstate2] = context['state2'];
```

Or directly :

```
const [state1,setstate1] = React.useContext(MyContext)['state1'];
const [state2,setstate2] = React.useContext(MyContext)['state2'];
```

You can add how many states you want.

Comment: There's the problem that I'm discussing in point 1 of my post: in this way when I update state 3 the keyed object will be re-built causing the children to be re-built as well (since context address changes, because it is a new object) even if state1 and state2 (the ones in the context) didn't change. This is the problem that I want to "solve"

Comment: @AndreaCostanzo1 Then this is where you should use the `useMemo` hook. [You can find it discussed here on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156)

Comment: @AreebKhan can you do a post. I'd like to leave the answer to this post. Just to confirm your answer and leave it for readers

Comment: `useMemo` and maybe `useReducer` depending on what you want to pass down.
Here is a great [blog post](https://hswolff.com/blog/how-to-usecontext-with-usereducer/) that helped me understand how it works.

Comment: @nico263nico I tried to wrap up all your answers in a post. Tell me if I'm missing something

Comment: @AreebKhan I tried to wrap up all your answers in a post. Tell me if I'm missing something